# Djongo isn't using my explicitly set primary key in Django models

Tags: django, django-models, djongo

Djongo using "id" as primary_key even though it is already explicitly set in model

below is my model, where ive explicitly set a primary key for each model.

```
class searchPlayers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
    playerId = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    LP = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    add_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
    
class Matches(models.Model):
    matchID = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    otherParticipants = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    placement = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    game_time = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    game_length = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')

    searchedPlayer= models.ForeignKey(searchPlayers, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)

class Traits(models.Model):
    matchID = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    traitname = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    currenttier = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tierunits = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    associatedMatch = models.ForeignKey(Matches,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)

class Champions(models.Model):
    matchID = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
    Star = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    Items = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='') #will have to delineate with commas
    Rarity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    associatedMatch = models.ForeignKey(Matches,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
```

and yet when i view on Mongo compass:
[Mongocompass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW9UK.png)
the primary key is still the "id" field.

ive tried deleting all my migrations, django.migrations and completely dumped my entire model. Any ideas for why the primary key isnt being properly set?

Comment: Does your set PK work in the shell? `python manage.py shell` + `{import models}` + `Traits.objects.filter(pk='{a_match_id}')` 
I'm curious if this is an actual feature of the abstract API..
I'm under the impression that filtering/joining by the auto-increment is *faster*.. So they might present it to you correctly through the api but in the backend decided to do what is faster.

Comment: @Nealium nope, the primary key is set as the default auto incremented in the shell to :( its weird because i was successfully able to get this working in another table that was simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `id` field is automatically generated when you run migrations in Django.
so in your case if you want a character field as primary key you can override the `id` field in all models.

for example:

```
class searchPlayers(models.Model):
id = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='')
LP = models.IntegerField(default=0)
add_date = models.DateTimeField('date')
```

first delete your old migrations files and then make your all models like this.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work. It feels like a bad solution though, being forced to name it id

Comment: Django works on ORM(Object Relational Mapper) technology, so whenever a database entry is created it automatically gets an id field just because to differentiate it to other entries. I told you a way by which you can give specific features like uuid or slug to your id. If it seems you a little right then upward my answer by clicking on the upward sign.